# Clustered index doesn't work with IN and OR clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have clustered in( PK) for instance table user.

When I search by particular user id it uses index seek.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE user.user_id = 1;
```

If i add OR or change to IN clause it will start to use index scan

```
SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE user.user_id = 1 
or user.user_id = 2

SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE user.user_id  in (1,2);
```

Is there some option to compel use seek index instead of scan?
If somebody know the reason i will be grateful to any explanation?

Comment: Can you include your table definition? This doesn't happen in my database.

Comment: Also, it may be useful to include the plans (see: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: Whether an index seek or an index scan, performance won't be affected. A seek is being used when SQL can access the row directly. If a range is involved, a scan is required. Either way the index will be used and performance won't be affected. It has nothing to do with a clustered index.

Comment: @SSteven I'm almost 102% positive that's not correct. OP please provide the plan (brent ozars site is great as DavidG posted).

Comment: @JacobH, which aspect of my comment are you referring to? Thanks.

Comment: You and I know that `1` and `2` are likely to be close together in the index. But it would be bizarrely specific for SQL Server to have an optimization that first has to determine that all values are co-located in the index. If you help the server out by asking for `user_id >= 1 and user_id <= 2` do you get the index seek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index Scan is nothing but scanning on the data pages from the first page to the last page. If there is an index on a table, and if the query is touching a larger amount of data, which means the query is retrieving more than 50 percent or 90 percent of the data, and then the optimizer would just scan all the data pages to retrieve the data rows. If there is no index, then you might see a Table Scan (Index Scan) in the execution plan.

Index seeks are generally preferred for the highly selective queries. What that means is that the query is just requesting a fewer number of rows or just retrieving the other 10 (some documents says 15 percent) of the rows of the table.

How many rows are with user id 1 and 2? how many total rows that you have right there?